# Putting module init/exit callbacks declaration in a header file?

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I'm very new in Linux Kernel Module development and have a question regarding the module structure. Consider the following simple module:

**Case 1.**

`init.h`

```
#include <linux/module.h>

int __init bda_init(void);

void __exit bda_exit(void);

module_init(bda_init);
module_exit(bda_exit);
```

`init.c`

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include "init.h"

int __init bda_init(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Init module\n");
    return 0;
}

void __exit bda_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Exit module\n");
}
```

The problem I thought about when implementing initialization in such a way was that the `bda_init` and `bda_exit` function both declared with external linkage and therefore should be linked into a kernel code. I examined `/proc/kallsyms`

```
$ grep "bda" /proc/kallsyms 
0000000000000000 r _note_6      [bda_md]
0000000000000000 d __this_module        [bda_md]
0000000000000000 t cleanup_module       [bda_md]
0000000000000000 t bda_exit     [bda_md]
```

and found out that `bda_exit` was appeared in the kallsyms, but `bda_int` was not.

**Case 2.**

When rewriting the module simply as

```
#include <linux/module.h>

static int __init bda_init(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Init module\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit bda_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Exit module\n");
}

module_init(bda_init);
module_exit(bda_exit);
```

I thougt it would make `bda_exit` disappear from the `kallsyms`, but it did not. The kallsyms are exactly the same:

```
$ grep "bda" /proc/kallsyms                                                                                                                                                       
0000000000000000 t bda_exit     [bda_md]
0000000000000000 r _note_6      [bda_md]
0000000000000000 d __this_module        [bda_md]
0000000000000000 t cleanup_module       [bda_md]
```

***QUESTION*:** Why does not the `static` declaration affect the `ksyms` introduced by a module and is it a common practice to declare init/exit callbacks in a header when implementing LKM?

Comment: Because `__exit` and `__init`. `init/exit callbacks in a header` You never implement implement a header for init/exit entrypoints of your modules, cause only kernel code will call them from appropriate sections. `declared with external linkage and therefore should be linked into a kernel` - is your kernel module static or dynamic? Did you modprobe your kernel module or did you compile your kernel module with the kernel?

Comment: @KamilCuk _Did you modprobe your kernel module?_ I `insmod`ed dynamically.